# Android volley post params other than string

Tags: android, post, request, android-volley

I'm using Volley lib to fire my requests. I created a custom class which extends `Request<T>` like this :

```
class CustomRequest<T> extends Request<T>
```

Every request with GET works very well.

I have some requests to do with POST method. For example the login requires the login and pwd, so I put in the Map in getParams() of the class, everything is fine. But I have a problem on another request, because I need to put params with any type of value like, int, array, etc... And the example here is to manage to pass this in a the request with POST :

```
{"items":[12926315]}
```

So, how can I do this, because Volley accepts only Map, and I get of course a 400 error code.

Many thanks for your help !

Comment: you could use declare a custom `BasicNameValuePair`  when you're making the request.

Comment: But the BasicNameValuePair waits for a "String, String" too right ? I can't see how to build it in order to pass the {"items":[12926315]} format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found why it didn't work, I needed to override the `getBodyContentType()` method

```
public String getBodyContentType()
    {
        return "application/json";
    }
```

And now it works ! Hope this'll help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StringRequest extends Request<String> {
private final Listener<String> mListener;
/**
 * Creates a new request with the given method.
 *
 * @param method the request {@link Method} to use
 * @param url URL to fetch the string at
 * @param listener Listener to receive the String response
 * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors
 */
public StringRequest(int method, String url, Listener<String> listener,
        ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, errorListener);
    mListener = listener;
}
/**
 * Creates a new POST request.
 *
 * @param url URL to fetch the string at
 * @param listener Listener to receive the String response
 * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors
 */
public StringRequest(String url, Listener<String> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    this(Method.POST, url, listener, errorListener);
}
@Override
protected void deliverResponse(String response) {
    mListener.onResponse(response);
}
@Override
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    String parsed;
    try {
        parsed = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        parsed = new String(response.data);
    }
    return Response.success(parsed, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
}
```

}

Hopefully this will good.

Comment: Thanks Rajeev ;) One question how to pass post params in your example ? I just edited my post, if you can take a look on it, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

So if I use `JsonObjectRequest` like below, and pass the JSONObject POST data, it works very well, but I would like to POST my JSONObject in the `getBody` of Volley in my class which extends `Request<T>` but it doesn't work because the JSONObject is casted I guess and add some quotes

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, dataToPost,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d("LOG", "+++++++++ success");
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("LOG", "--------- error");
                    }
                })
                {
                };
```

Here my JSONObject :

```
JSONObject dataToPost = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsa = new JSONArray();
jsa.put(12926315);
jsa.put(12998018); 
dataToPost.put("items", jsa);
```

And here the getBody method :

```
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
return postJson.toString().getBytes();  // postJson is dataToPost     
    }
```

But from server side, the response is {"items":'[12926315, 12998018]'} while it waits for {"items":[12926315, 12998018]}

Any idea ?